# Problems With Sorting A 2D String Array Using Columns In Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting

I am creating a leaderboard that is part of a game that I am working on. Basically, the code I have stores the user's name in the first column and the score associated with that user's name in the second column in a 2D array. It sorts the 2D array in descending order according to the score numbers in the second column. This is the code I have:

```
String line = null;
String lineCounter = null;

try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("scores.txt"));
    while ((lineCounter = br.readLine()) != null) {
        lineCount++;
    }

    String[][] scores = new String[lineCount][2];
    int x = 0;

    BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("scores.txt"));
    while ((line = BR.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] nums = line.split(": ");
        scores[x][0] = nums[0];
        scores[x][1] = nums[1];
        x++;
    }

    Arrays.sort(scores, new Comparator<String[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(final String[] first, final String[] second) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return Double.valueOf(second[1]).compareTo(
                Double.valueOf(first[1])
            );
        }
    });
    String[][] theCopy = Arrays.copyOf(scores, scores.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < theCopy.length; i++) {
        System.out.print((i + 1) + ". ");
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            if(j == 0) System.out.print(theCopy[i][j] + ": ");
            if(j == 1) System.out.print(theCopy[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This code is inside a while loop. The user has the option to see the leaderboard as many times as they want until the press the correct number to terminate the program. So the problem I have is when the user decides to view the leaderboard, it works the first time, but when the user wants to view the leaderboard a second time, the program crashes.

This is the error message I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at prjTicTacToe.TicTacToe$1.compare(TicTacToe.java:200)
    at prjTicTacToe.TicTacToe$1.compare(TicTacToe.java:1)
    at java.util.TimSort.binarySort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
    at prjTicTacToe.TicTacToe.main(TicTacToe.java:195)
```

How do I fix this so the user can view the leaderboard as many times as they want before they want to terminate the program?

Comment: @Henry Can you help me fix the problem instead of declaring duplicate?

Comment: Did you read the answers in the referenced post? You need to grow some debugging skills. The stack trace tells you that the NPE happens in TicTacToe.java line 200. Now find out why the array element is null.

Comment: @Henry This is the line that's giving the NPE error. `return Double.valueOf(second[1]).compareTo(Double.valueOf(first[1]));` Code works fine during the first run, but the next run is where errors occur.